# BeautifulSoup only returning 20 element per page when there are 30 elements per page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** data (medicine name) from this link https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines this link have 841 pages with 30 data per page. But my code is somehow only picking 20 data per page. I don't know what causing it and how to solve it.
this is the code I am using.

```
import requests
import json
import io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
medicine_name = []
f = io.open('data.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
for i in range(1,842):
    url = "https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines?page=" + str(i)

    r = requests.get(url)
    HTMLcontent = r.content


    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTMLcontent, 'html.parser')



    json_data = json.loads(
        soup.select_one("script").string
    )

    for data in json_data['itemListElement']:
        medicine_name.append(data['name'])
        f.write('\n'+data['name'])
    print("parsed --> " + str(len(medicine_name)) + " from page No. --> " + str(i) + "")
    medicine_name = []
        
f.close()
```

I am getting this output:

```
PS E:\Practice\Python\1mg Scraper> & D:/Python396/python.exe "e:/Practice/Python/1mg Scraper/tool.py"
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 1
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 2
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 3
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 4
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 5
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 6
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 7
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 8
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 9
...................................
<-----------Upto------------------>
...................................
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 837
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 838
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 839
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 840
parsed --> 20 from page No. --> 841
```

I am expecting output that is something like

`parsed --> 30 from page No. --> xxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header. Without it, the server returns different type of page:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}


for i in range(1, 842):
    url = "https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines?page=" + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    json_data = json.loads(
        soup.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').string
    )

    for data in json_data["itemListElement"]:
        print(data["name"])
```

Prints 30 products per page:

```
Ascoril D Plus Syrup Sugar Free
Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet
Allegra 180mg Tablet
Azithral 500 Tablet
Ascoril LS Syrup
Avil 25 Tablet
Allegra 120mg Tablet

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but I forgot to mention. By the way can you tell me why I am getting difference in your code and my code?

Comment: @DivyanshuGupta The server probably returns two version of pages (depending which `User-Agent` HTTP header you send with your requests. Here in my code I specify the `User-Agent` from my Firefox browser.

Comment: And how can I find the user agent?

Comment: @DivyanshuGupta You can find user agent in Firefox (or Chrome) developer tools -> Network tab (under request headers).

Comment: Okay @AndrejKesly Thanks a lot for your help.